# Sound not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04. But I didn't manage to make the audio to work. I already have tried several things, including reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, and messing around with /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, but with no success so far...

Some information about my system:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=29ff83a6364f6432521c8eb30774fc33a5524fe0

Any help would be much appreciated.